# Three.js does not show texture on sphere

Tags: google-chrome, textures, webgl, three.js

There are some threads about textures which do not showing up. I have tried them all, but nothing helped.

I have spent a few hours on this now. Every time I end up looking at a black sphere.

I am working on Chrome v18 and Windows 7. I also tried Firefox, but this browser does not really support Three.js.

This is the body of the script:

```
<body>

    <script src="../build/Three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

This is the script itself:

```
// stap1) camera, set the scene size
    var WIDTH = 400,
        HEIGHT = 300;

    // set some camera attributes
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
        ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
        NEAR = 0.1,
        FAR = 10000;

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  
                VIEW_ANGLE,
          ASPECT,
          NEAR,
          FAR  );
// stap2) scene:                
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
   scene.add(camera);
     camera.position.z = +300;
    // get the DOM element to attach to
    // - assume we've got jQuery to hand
    var container = $('#container');

    // stap3)create a WebGL renderer:
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    // start the renderer
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    // attach the render-supplied DOM element
    container.append(renderer.domElement);

    // bol maken:
    // create the sphere's material
    // b.v: THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
    {
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("http://dev.root.nl/tree/examples/textures/ash_uvgrid01.jpg")
    });

    // set up the sphere vars
    var radius = 50, segments = 16, rings = 16;
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings); 
    // create a new mesh with sphere geometry -
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
       sphereGeometry,
       sphereMaterial
         );

    sphere.position.x=0;
    var s=1;
    sphere.scale.set(s, s, s);  

    // add the sphere to the scene
    scene.add(sphere);
    // create a point light
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );
    // set its position
    pointLight.position.x = 10;
    pointLight.position.y = 50;
    pointLight.position.z = 130;
    // add to the scene
    scene.add(pointLight);
    // draw!
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait until the image used as texture is fully downloaded.

I have put your code on the web: http://jsfiddle.net/4Qg7K/ and just added a classic "render loop":

```
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  sphere.rotation.y += 0.005; //rotation stuff, just for fun

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

`requestAnimationFrame` function works like a timer, calling to the `render` function each time the browser is ready to update the web page.

BTW, Three.js works fine with Firefox.